# hadoop - DBInputFormat causing error when configuring object

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, hadoop, mapreduce

I know that my error revolves around the fact that not all the nodes in my cluster don't see the Postgresql driver jar, but I don't know which file to edit to have the postgres jar visible to all nodes. The question is how to I get all of my nodes see the postgres.jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I needed to place the postgres library into the $HADOOP_HOME/lib directory

Comment: That's one good solution. Other options: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/

Comment: That's actually the same page I found XD Thanks for the link. It was very useful one.